# Php - replace question mark sign

Tags: php

Is it possible to replace php tags to something custom?

Smarty library can assign values and then render them so instead of:

```
<?php echo $name; ?>
```

you can just assign value in business logic and then in template just say

```
{name}
```

I'd like to make my own function/class/library so when I write { in index.tpl, browser will think its < ?php echo ..

Can somebody point me somewhere?

Comment: I'd just use plain PHP: `<?= $name ?>`; it's fairly clean and it doesn't have the overhead of a template engine. After all, PHP itself is template engine. Use [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and you're golden.

Comment: 't would be a nightmare: `{if(var){` => `<?php if(var)<?php`... which is not what you want, which means you have to build a custom parser, with all kinds of things to keep track of. _Why_ do you think you need this?

Comment: The browser never sees the ?. It is part of the php processing taking place on the server side. After that the browser receives HTML.

Comment: ... and I agree with @NullUserException: the best template engine for PHP is... PHP.

Comment: short tags `<?= ?>` > templates

Comment: Thank you guys imma go with <?= ?>

Answer (score 2):

replace {variable} with regexps and then eval-it

[here](http://git.twista.cz/exportify/src) is simple template engine, very similar to your idea

i mean, better is use existing templates engines, like [Latte](http://doc.nette.org/en/templating), [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). Its not necessary reinventing wheel :)